# While loop taking a long time to complete

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a `while loop` that I feel should run much faster, but it takes up to 50 seconds to go through a maximum of 350 rows in the website.

I have tried making separate if statements, but that took the same amount of time.

```
while 'x' not in driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[1]/span').text.strip():
                VAR1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]').text.strip()
                if driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[1]/span').text.strip() == 'Y':
                    VAR2 = ''
                    VAR2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[2]/span').text.strip()
                elif driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[1]/span').text.strip() == 'Z':
                    VAR3 = ''
                    VAR3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[2]/span').text.strip()
                elif driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[1]/span').text.strip() == 'A':
                    VAR4 = ''
                    VAR4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[2]/span').text.strip()
                elif driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[1]/span').text.strip() == 'B':
                    VAR5 = ''
                    VAR5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[2]/span').text.strip()
                elif driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[1]/span').text.strip() == 'C':
                    VAR6 = ''
                    VAR6 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[2]/span').text.strip()
                elif driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[1]/span').text.strip() == 'D':
                    VAR7 = ''
                    VAR7 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[2]/span').text.strip()
                elif driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[1]/span').text.strip() == 'E':
                    VAR8 = ''
                    VAR8 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[2]/span').text.strip()
                else:
                    pass
                output = VAR1 + '|' + VAR2 + '|' + VAR3 + '|' + VAR4 + '|' + VAR5 + '|' + VAR6 + '|' + VAR7 + '|' + VAR8
                print(output)
                n += 1
else:
     n += 1
```

I am getting the proper output, but it is taking a long time. Is there anything that I can do to increase the speed of my loop?

Comment: You're continually calling `find_element_by_xpath()` on the same two xpath values.  I imagine this is a somewhat expensive operation.  Call it _once_ for each desired xpath, save the result, and then check the result in your `if` statements instead of calling it again.

Comment: @JohnGordon This sped up the program a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you're calling a non-trivial function somewhere from 3 to 9 times, and most of those calls simply repeat a search you've already done.  Call the function *once* for each line you want to examine, store the result, and compare against that.

```
# This call has no variables; do it only once
VAR1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]').text.strip()

# Let a `for` handle your counter; break the loop when done.
for n in range(len(your_table)):
    row_n = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/th/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td[1]/span').text.strip()
    if x in row_n:
        break
    elif row_n = "Y":
        ...
```

Also consider handling your series of `VARn` variables with a list; you could index the target strings with a similar list `["Y", "A", ...]` and then build your output line with an inner loop and a `join` call.

Comment: Changing question details after an answer is posted?  Not nice ... now the answer requires editing to remain correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use xpath axis for locating elements in different positions. Using loops have a higher cost on the code and it takes unwanted time to reach the specific element. Now with xpath axis you can easily traverse between the xpaths upward or downward in the DOM.

Comment: What does DOM stand for?

Comment: It's stands for Document Object Model you can visit for reference https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/introduction.html